# Reference to Screen Manager

Tags: android, python, kivy

Is it possible to refer to the screen manager using the object of the screen in python?
Basically I want to change the screen from python.

In kivy it is simple:

```
app.root.current='ScreenName'
```

I don't want to create a new screen manager object here.

I do this because in kivy language I use this code:

```
on_release: root.select_experiment();app.root.current= 'StartExperiment'
```

The `root.select_experiment()` calls a pop. I want the transition to happen to StartExperiment screen only after the pop-up is dismissed. From kivy it happens before.
EDIT:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\test\main.py", line 171, in <module>
     AppBaseClass().run()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 824, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 525, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 290, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 330, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 281, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 699, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:7011)
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors.py", line 163, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 695, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:6970)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1168, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12154)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1092, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:11729)
   File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\test\main.py", line 84, in file_button_clicked
     self.parent.ids.MyScreenManager.current = 'StartExperiment'
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 720, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:10911)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is to give the screen manager an ID in kivy language, and then reference that ID form Python.

## Kivy file

```
ScreenManager:
    id: MyScreenManager
```

## Python

```
self.parent.current = 'Target_Screen'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the error posted in edit. Please kindly check it.

Comment: Building on what you said. The correct answer seems to be `self.parent.current`

Comment: Cool! I'll edit my answer to reflect the correct code :) That means that setting the ID in the Kivy file is no necessary